# Blank Screen at boot Ubuntu 12.04 - nvidia-current - Macbook Air 3,2

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, macbook-air

I've installed nvidia-current using the Additional Drivers application in Ubuntu 12.04.
I need those drivers so I can use accelerated WebGL.

After installing the drivers, and rebooting X fails to start and I have a frozen system/dark screen.

Below is the content of Xorg.0.log

How can I fix this problem?

```
    [     4.666] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[     4.666] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.666] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-23-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     4.666] Current Operating System: Linux david-macbook-air 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012 x86_64
[     4.666] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=b3d5ae2a-72af-4ef9-b775-0d40b5f80f9b ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     4.666] Build Date: 29 August 2012  12:12:33AM
[     4.666] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     4.666] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[     4.666]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.666] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.666] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Dec 13 10:18:02 2012
[     4.668] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.668] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     4.668] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     4.668] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     4.668] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     4.668] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     4.668] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.668] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.668] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.668]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.668] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     4.668]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.669] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     4.669]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.669] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     4.669]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.669] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     4.669]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.669] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[     4.669]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.669] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     4.669] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.669] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     4.669] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6222467b00
[     4.669] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.669]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.669]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[     4.669]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[     4.669]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[     4.670] (--) PCI:*(0:2:0:0) 10de:08a3:106b:00d3 rev 162, Mem @ 0x92000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00001000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     4.670] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[     4.670] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[     4.671] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[     4.671] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.671]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.671]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.671]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[     4.671] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[     4.671] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[     4.671] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.671]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.671]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.671]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.671] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     4.671] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.671] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     4.869] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     4.869]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.869]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.869] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:57:38 PDT 2012
[     4.869] (II) Loading extension GLX
[     4.869] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[     4.870] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[     4.870] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.870]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[     4.870]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.870]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.870] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[     4.870] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     4.870] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     4.870] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.870]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.870]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.870] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[     4.870] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     4.871] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[     4.871] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.871]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[     4.871]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[     4.871] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[     4.871] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     4.871] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     4.871] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[     4.871] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     4.871] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[     4.871] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     4.871] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     4.871] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     4.887] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     4.887]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.887]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.892] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     4.894] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     4.894] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.894]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.2
[     4.894]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.894]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.894] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[     4.895] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[     4.895] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[     4.895] (II) Unloading nv
[     4.895] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[     4.895] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     4.895] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     4.896] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.896]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[     4.896]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.896]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.896] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     4.896] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     4.896] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.896]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[     4.896]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.896] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     4.896] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     4.896] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[     4.896] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     4.896] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[     4.896] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     4.896] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     4.896] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     4.896] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     4.896]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.896]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.896] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     4.896] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     4.896] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 32610)
[     4.896] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     4.897] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     4.897] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.897]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.2
[     4.897]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.897]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.897] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[     4.897] (II) Unloading nouveau
[     4.897] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 32610)
[     4.897] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[     4.897] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[     4.897] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[     4.897] (II) Unloading nv
[     4.897] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[     4.897] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     4.898] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     4.898] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.898]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[     4.898]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     4.898]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.898] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     4.898] (II) Unloading vesa
[     4.898] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[     4.898] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     4.898] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     4.898] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.898]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[     4.898]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.898] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     4.898] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     4.899] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[     4.899] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:38:35 PDT 2012
[     4.899] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     4.899] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Sep 12 13:42:43 2012 +0200
[     4.899] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     4.899]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[     4.899]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[     4.899]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[     4.899]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[     4.899]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[     4.899]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[     4.900]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[     4.900]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[     4.900]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[     4.900]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[     4.900]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[     4.900]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[     4.900]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[     4.900] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     4.900] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     4.900] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.902] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     4.902] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     4.902] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     4.902] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.902]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.902]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     4.902] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     4.902] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     4.903] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     4.905] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.905]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.905]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     4.905] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     4.905] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     4.905] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     4.907] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     4.907] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     4.907] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     4.912] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     4.912] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     4.912] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     4.912] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     4.912] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     4.912] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.912]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[     4.912]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     4.912] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     4.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     4.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     4.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     4.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     4.912] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     5.442] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the display subsystem for the NVIDIA
[     5.442] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     graphics device!
[     5.442] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to get supported display device(s)
[     5.442] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize dac HAL
[     5.442] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.442] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     5.442] (II) UnloadModule: "wfb"
[     5.442] (II) Unloading wfb
[     5.442] (II) UnloadModule: "fb"
[     5.443] (II) Unloading fb
[     5.443] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[     5.443] 
Fatal server error:
[     5.443] no screens found
[     5.443] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     5.443] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     5.443] 
[     5.447]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
[     5.447] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and it turned out that it was because Linux was booting in EFI mode instead of BIOS compatibility mode. The binary NVIDIA driver requires something from the (fake) BIOS in order to work properly. There are a few options to deal with this. The easiest is to boot off of a burned install CD and just reinstall because that will install grub-pc instead of grub-efi. Another option is to do `apt-get install grub-pc` and that will fix the issue as well, but you'll have to actually get to a point where you can boot up and install it which requires network access.

The info I found that helped me fix it was here:

http://martys.typepad.com/blog/2012/10/kubuntu-macbook-efi-and-nvidia.html